# Get elements between two dates

Tags: python, date

Attributes generated as below

```
['2013-05-10T13:07:19.425602+01:00', 'seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=2', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=103']
['2013-05-10T13:07:19.586633+01:00', 'seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=21', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1021']
['2013-05-20T13:07:21.842280+01:00', 'seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=28', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1028']
['2013-05-21T13:07:21.853704+01:00', setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=29', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1897']
['2013-05-21T13:07:19.425602+01:00', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=211', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2020']
['2013-05-22T13:07:19.586633+01:00', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=212', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2021']
['2013-05-22T13:07:21.842280+01:00', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=218', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2023']
['2013-05-22T13:07:21.853704+01:00', seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=291', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2024']
```

I need to get the attributes between two dates say `2013-05-21 13:07:19` and `2013-05-22 13:07:19`

```
for line in pass:
    if string.find(line, searchterm) != -1:
    attributes = line.split()   
        start = attributes[0]
    start = start[:-13] 
    start = strptime(start, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
    #print start
    untill = start+timedelta(days=1)
    #print untill


    #delta = start - untill
    for i in attributes:
      month, day, year hours:minutes:seconds = i[0].split('-')
      r_date = date(year, month, day hours:minutes:seconds)
      if r_date >= start_date and r_date <= end_date:
         return attributes.append(i)
```

Can anyone guide me ? How to get the attributes between two dates ?

expected output:

```
['2013-05-21 13:07:21', setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=29', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1897']
['2013-05-21 13:07:19', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=211', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2020']
['2013-05-22 13:07:19', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=212', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2021']
['2013-05-22 13:07:21', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=218', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2023']
['2013-05-22 13:07:21', seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=291', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2024']
```

how to specify the start and end dates as usr input?

Modifyed Bit :

```
startdate = raw_input("Enter start date as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS :") 
enddate = raw_input ("Enter end date as  YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS :") 
            try: 
                   start = datetime.datetime.strptime(startdate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  
            end = datetime.datetime.strptime(enddate, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

            except ValueError:
            print "Invalid date"                                


            for item in attributes:

           _date = datetime.datetime(time.strptime(item[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
        on compilation at this section it gives an error time data 2 doesnot match the format  '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' why is considering only the first digit of the date ?
```

Answer (score 3):

It is easier to make this check if you use `datetime` objects.

First define your start and end date as `datetime` object

```
start = datetime(2013, 5, 21, 13, 7, 19) 
end = datetime(2013, 5, 22, 13, 7, 19)
```

Say your data is in `my_values` list like

```
my_values = [
    ['2013-05-10T13:07:19.425602+01:00', 'seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=2', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=103']
    ['2013-05-10T13:07:19.586633+01:00', 'seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=21', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1021']
    ['2013-05-20T13:07:21.842280+01:00', 'seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=28', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1028']
    ['2013-05-21T13:07:21.853704+01:00', setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=29', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=1897']
    ['2013-05-21T13:07:19.425602+01:00', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=211', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2020']
    ['2013-05-22T13:07:19.586633+01:00', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=212', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2021']
    ['2013-05-22T13:07:21.842280+01:00', 'setc', 'zone14', 'status=Info', 'id=218', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2023']
    ['2013-05-22T13:07:21.853704+01:00', seta', 'zone1', 'status=Info', 'id=291', 'MSG="New', 'Request', 'Arrival"','Reqno=2024']
]
```

Create a new list:

```
my_selected_values = []
```

Loop through your current list and select the dates you want

```
for item in my_values:
    _date = datetime.strptime(item[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')  # parse datetime from string
    if start <= _date <= end:  # check if it is within your time interval
        my_selected_values.append([_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')] + item[1:])
```

If `item` datetime is within your range, then you re-format the related datetime value as a string of your choice and add the rest of the values. `[_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')]` will let you format your datetime data as you wish and `+ item[1:]` will add the rest of the items in your orginal list and create an output as you wish. Finally you will `return my_selected_values`

Update: As for getting start and end time from users, you can use `raw_input` (python 2.x) or `input` (python 3.x) and then parse the input string to datetime object. Like:

```
_start_date = raw_input("Enter start date as YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS")  # You can specify input format as you wish since you will parse the string manually
try: 
    start = datetime.strftime(_start_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')  # use your datetime input format you specify above
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid date input"
```

Or , if you wish, you can get datetime parameters (year, month, day etc...) one by one with each input and then create datetime objext with that

```
_year = int(raw_input("Year"))
_month = int(raw_input("month"))
etc...
start = datetime(_year, _month, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot is there any way to specify the start and end datetime object as usr input like start = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second) end = datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute,second)

Comment: When i tried to implement above Im popped up with attribute strftime , strptime not found error Im using python 2.7.6 I tried to modify the code as above and on execution at below code section it gives an error time data 2 doesnot match the format  '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S' why is considering only the first digit of the date ?  _date = datetime.datetime(time.strptime(attributes[0], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))

Comment: You may forgot to `import` required libraries with `from datetime import datetime`. You can check documentation from here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects

Comment: I have imported them using import datetime from datetime import datetime

Comment: `time.strptime(attributes[0]`? It was i a loop and the loop variable is named `item`, which is the datetime string in your each list.

Comment: Sorry By mistake it was posted as attributes. However It is able to strp only the First digit from the date i.e 2 stating 
time data '2' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'

Comment: Examine my example, I give initial data as a list of lists. I loop through the list and select the first element of each inner list, which is the datetime string. IIf you do not have a list of lists or you are just working on a single list, then you do not need to use the loop. Also, you have to read more about datetime so you can understand the meaning of possible errors you will get.